# What is "QApplication app(argc, argv)" trying to do?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtDeclarative>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;

    viewer.setMainQmlFile("app/native/assets/main.qml");
    viewer.showFullScreen();

    return app.exec();
}
```

My C++ is a bit rusty.  Can someone please explain to me what is "QApplication app(argc, argv)" trying to do ?

Is it trying to declare a function which takes in 2 arguments (argc and argv) and return a variable of type QApplication ?

Answer (score 13):

The line

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

creates a new instance of type `QApplication` and invokes the constructor of this class. In your example, the variable `app` now stores this instance. It is *somewhat* (semantically) a shorthand of this:

```
QApplication app = QApplication(argc, argv);
```

Comment: why that statement doesn’t require the "new" keyword  
QApplication app = new QApplication(argc, argv);

Comment: @DScript: with `new` you'd dynamically allocate an object on the heap. When you use `new` you'd get a pointer instead. So you'd have to do this: `QApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv);`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quote from Qt Docs:

> The QApplication class manages the GUI application's control flow and
>   main settings.
>
> QApplication contains the main event loop, where all events from the
>   window system and other sources are processed and dispatched. It also
>   handles the application's initialization, finalization, and provides
>   session management. In addition, QApplication handles most of the
>   system-wide and application-wide settings.
>
> For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely one QApplication
>   object, no matter whether the application has 0, 1, 2 or more windows
>   at any given time. For non-GUI Qt applications, use QCoreApplication
>   instead, as it does not depend on the QtGui library.
>
> The QApplication object is accessible through the instance() function
>   that returns a pointer equivalent to the global qApp pointer.

So, the line

`QApplication app(argc, argv);`

creates an instance of the QApplication class.

Answer (score 3):

QApplication is a Qt class that contains the main event loop.

When you write `QApplication app(argc, argv);`
you are creating a object `app` of this class, by calling its constructor with `argc` and `argv`

When `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is called while running the program, `int argc` is intialized to contain the number of arguments passed while running the program. `char **argv` contains an array of arguments passed to the program when executing it.

char* argv[0] will contain (point to) the name of the program, while the subsequent elements will point to the other arguments passed.

argc and argv are in turn, passed to the constructor of QApplication, so that one can pass Qt specific arguments when running your program.

For an example of such arguments try running `./yourProgramName --help` in a terminal window

Answer (score 2):

app() is not a function, it is a constructor call.

If you come from C# or Java or something, imagine it as

```
QApplication app = new QApplication( argc, argv );
```

Just that app would be a pointer this way, while it actually is the object itself if it is created like in your example.

In short, Qt needs a `QApplication` instance to run so signals&slots are processed (if you are using them) and events like painting etc are handled